# Jquery gradient behavior applies to all but first URL

Tags: jquery

I've got a [page](http://www.fifephotography.com/index.php/admin/portfolio) that shows my photography portfolio. I'm trying to do a jquery gradient on the text, and it's working on all but the first link. Here's the html:

```
<h1><a href="portfolio/engagements"><span></span>engagements</a>  | </h1><br>
<h1><a href="portfolio/weddings"><span></span>weddings</a>  |  </h1>    <br>
<h1><a href="portfolio/bridals"><span></span>bridals</a>  |  </h1>  <br>
<h1><a href="portfolio/families"><span></span>families</a>  |  </h1>    <br>
<h1><a href="portfolio/seniors"><span></span>seniors</a>  </h1>     <br>
```

And here's the jquery call:

```
$(".jquery h1").prepend("<span></span>");
```

And here's the css for it:

```
.gradient4 span {
    background: url(images/gradient-dark.png) repeat-x;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -0.1em;
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    height: 29px;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that all urls but the first link (currently 'engagements'), have the gradient effect. Any ideas why the first link isn't working?

Comment: Seems to be working just fine here ...

Comment: Let me rephrase that - in IE8 (standards mode) and FF 3 it's working fine.  There's no gradient at all in IE7 and it spontaneously breaks in IE8 quirks mode ...

Comment: what browser are you using? I've seen it on FF, Chrome, and Safari.

Comment: so the first link, "engagements" isn't currently all white?

Comment: Why all the empty `<span>` tags? And why prepend more?

Comment: I was using it from another website: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect/

Comment: Fair enough. So I assume you're using some sort of gradient plugin. I also assume that the `h1` elements are all inside a container with class `jquery`. What we probably need to see is the code that actually applies the gradient to the text. Could you add that to your question?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's now in the original question.

Comment: I was about to edit your question to improve the formatting a little, and noticed `<br>` tags in your css. I'll remove them as I assume they're not in your code, and you were trying to format. To format your code, select it, and click the Code Sample button above the edit area. This will indent your code, which then applies formatting.

Comment: Now you're using a class called `gradient` and one called `jquery`, neither of which appear in your HTML. And you haven't verified if you're using a plugin. If so, you haven't shared the code that calls the plugin.

Comment: Looks like the javascript call wasn't doing anything...I commented it out and it didn't change anything. It looks like everything is controlled via css.....and thanks for the formatting suggestions! I'm very new to this.

Comment: Ok, so this isn't jQuery at all. Just a `<span>` element overlapping your text I assume. This is more of a design question that isn't really suited for stackoverflow, but I can tell you that the `<span>` that should be overlaying the "engagements" link is way off to the left. If you have a browser that lets you inspect elements (like Safari, Chrome or Firefox with Firebug), you can inspect the `<span>` that is next to "Engagements", and the element inspector will highlight that element. You'll see it way off to the left.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a design question as it turns out, but to give you an idea of what is happening, the `<span>` element that provides the gradient overlay is shifted way off to the left.

Here's a screen shot of the issue.

Look at the blue highlighted box all the way on the left. That's your overlay. It is positioned incorrectly somehow.

[alt text http://dalewhalen.com/stackoverflow/grad_overlay.png](http://dalewhalen.com/stackoverflow/grad_overlay.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that when you prepend the `<span>` and set with position:absolute, the first element is going to inherit its top- and left-values from its parent and, in this case, appear at the top-left position. Instead of using the `<span>`s, why not manipulate the `<h1>` using addClass and removeClass. Its hover state would get rendered as `<h1 class="gradient">` and its normal state it's just plain `<h1>`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm quite a newby....do you mean using some javascript to add and remove a class? I'm not very familiar with that technique. In any case, I ended up with a hack that made it work. It always didn't apply the style to the first element, so I made a new first element and made the text color black so you can't see it. Definitely not the best solution, but it works. Thanks!